# span tag not working at all

Tags: html, css

I have an html file a part of which is as follows:

```
<ul>
   {% for tree in tree}
         <li>   <a href="{{ url_for('fruits', tree_id=tree.id) }}">
            {{ tree.tree_name }} - {{ tree.tree_year }}
        </a> 
<span class="hyphen"> - </span>       
<a href="{{ url_for('stats', tree_id=tree.id) }}">
        stats
        </a></li>
       {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

and the corresponding .css is as follows:

```
.hyphen{ margin-left:80px; margin-right:80px }
```

But the span tag doesn't seem to have any effect at all. I want to give space before and after the hyphen but it isn't working. Why so?

Comment: Close this `{% for tree in tree` properly.

Comment: Shouldn't also be `for tree in trees`?

Comment: You must not be closing something correctly as margin left and right will work on an inline element [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/c3Lytjpw/).

Comment: The curly braces i forgot here. The real problem is something else but.

Comment: @ShaguftaOliveyuMethwani You can see in my demo that it works fine. You must not be sharing some code that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A `span` is by default an inline element, inline elements can't have vertical padding / margin.

To fix this you can do two things,
the first is to give the element `display: block` but this is most likely not what you want as it was inline before.

Then there's `display: inline-block` as noted by D4V1D which will give you the ability to style that span like a block level element.

Comment: How is this relevant? The OP wants left and right margin.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
.hyphen {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

to your `<span>`.

You can't set `width`, `height` and *vertical* `margin` and `padding` properties to elements which **aren't** `block` elements.

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: I want a space before and after the hyphen.Is there something other than span? that can help here?

Comment: Also this is untrue and incorrect. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/c3Lytjpw/) Why wouldn't you be able to pad or set a margin on inline elements? It will limit you to left/right.

Comment: Is this really the case? I can understand that vertical margins don't work on an inline element, but horizontal margin should work.

Comment: My bad, I thought it was for all `margin` actually, answer edited.

Comment: @D4V1D The answer is now not relevant to the question. This should not make a difference.